# How does protoc find definitions not on IMPORT_PATH?

Tags: protocol-buffers

In one of my .proto definitions, I import Google's timestamp definition:
`import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3),

> IMPORT_PATH specifies a directory in which to look for .proto files
> when resolving import directives.

I am pretty sure timestamp.proto is not on my IMPORT_PATH, which happens to be the current working directory.

Are `google` protobuf definitions special somehow? Are these google definitions installed locally, when `protoc` was installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are indeed special - they are referred to as [well-known types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf).

The compiler looks to resolve these imports [relative to where the `protoc` executable is installed](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/88d8f6001d4b14520488f23de36366b7df673373/src/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc#L245-L284); various locations are checked. If a location is found that contains proto definitions for the well-known types, this is location is looked at as a fall-back - in other words, a path relative to where the `protoc` executable is run is checked first, before checking the location with the well-known type definitions.

You can see this when executing the compiler with strace or dtruss, e.g. on OSX:

```
stat64("google/protobuf/timestamp.proto\0", 0x7FFEE4219B98, 0x0)                 = -1 2
open("google/protobuf/timestamp.proto\0", 0x0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)               = -1 2
stat64("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/21.8/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto\0", 0x7FFEE4219B98, 0x0)                 = 0 0
open("/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/21.8/include/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto\0", 0x0, 0x0)              = 3 0
```

Comment: Thanks for all these details - I don't see anything relevant in the protoc executable's directory, so I think those imports access `Cellar/protobuf/21.9_1/include`. And so they were installed at the same time as `protoc` was installed, as opposed to e.g. Maven/Gradle, which pull dependencies from APIs at build time.